# Momentum Vectors in Bondi coordinates

Tags: special-relativity, kinematics, momentum, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems

In the Bondi-Sachs formalism, we can define the notion of 'retarded' time via a coordinate transformation of the usual Minkowski metric
$$
d s^{2}=\eta_{\mu \nu} d x^{\mu} d x^{\nu}=-\left(d x^{0}\right)^{2}+\left(d x^{1}\right)^{2}+\left(d x^{2}\right)^{2}+\left(d x^{3}\right)^{2},
$$

defining the retarded time as $u = x^0 - r$, where $r = \sqrt{\left(x^{1}\right)^{2}+\left( x^{2}\right)^{2}+\left(x^{3}\right)^{2}}$. We can then define Bondi coordintes $(u,r, \theta,\phi)$ by further performing the spherical coordinate transformations
$$
x^{1} \pm i x^{2}=r e^{\pm i \phi} \sin \theta, \quad x^{3}=r \cos \theta.
$$

When it comes to a momentum four-vector, we can transform it to the spherical polar coordinate system by taking
$$
p^\mu = (E,p^1,p^2,p^3)\rightarrow (E, |\textbf{p}| \cos \varphi \sin \theta, |\textbf{p}| \sin \varphi \sin \theta, |\textbf{p}| \cos \theta).
$$

Can we also do a transformation to the energy, to define some sort of retarded energy, and if so what is its physical interpretation?

EDIT: It seems as if we can define either retarded or advanced energy, corresponding $\omega_+ = E+|\textbf{p}|$ or $\omega_-=E-|\textbf{p}|$. These only both seem valid in for massive momenta, since we can write
$$
\omega_+ = \frac{E^2 - |\textbf{p}|^2}{E-|\textbf{p}|} = \frac{m^2}{E-|\textbf{p}|},~~~~~\omega_- = \frac{m^2}{E+|\textbf{p}|}.
$$
In the massless limit, we find that $E = |\textbf{p}|$, assuming the principle square root, meaning $\omega_+ = 2E$ and $\omega_- = 0$. I've no idea what this means, but it does agree with the parameterization in the massless case.

Comment: The Bondi-Sachs formalism is aimed to study arbitrary asymptotically flat geometries. What you wrote e.g. u=t-r is only true for Minkowski metric. In general u is defined such that it is a null coordinate, which is not the case for t-r. Anyhow, maybe you can find the answer in the literature on "lightcone gauge".

Comment: I'm aware of that @AliSeraj, I consider the momentum to be defined in Minkowski space. I'll take a look at the lightcone gauge stuff, thanks!